# Date slicer in Power BI with past and future dates never used

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a fact table that goes from 01/01/2021 to 31/12/2022 with every sale made on this period. To compare some fact tables, i connected them to a calendar table created on power query, but this calendar table goes from 2001 to 2030. I want to keep it this way, this this many dates.
On this Calendar Table i created a column for MonthYear (january/2021, february/2022, etc).

My problem is: when i create a slicer and a put my MonthYear on the slicer, it is showing all of the MonthYear since 2001, and i just want it to show the MonthYears in the years that are covered by my sales dates.
How can I do that?

I tried filtering the slicer to where my SalesDate isn't empty or something, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. First check you have the correct relationship set up.  It should be a one (from calendar table) to im guessing many in fact table.  If you have only one fact per day, then it will be one to one.

1. Hard filter the slicer for the required data range
2. In DAX in your calendar table, create a new column called slicer filter.  Then using the 'related' function and an if statement. slicer filter = NOT(ISBLANK(RELATED(Table2[date])))
3. or slicer filter = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2), FILTER(Table2, Table2[Value]=Table1[Value])) > 0

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/If-column-contains-values-from-column-in-another-table/m-p/57271

Comment: It worked very fine! Thank you very much!